# Programming standards and principles to become better programmer

Tags: c#, architecture, coding-style, refactoring, standards

I am a c# developer.

I have always been interested in increasing my skills and knowledge and trying to pickup new technology.

However now I want to enhance my knowledge in Programming standards and principles. So for example I want to know about how to structure code, refactor code, coding standards and good practices etc...

Does anyone have any recommendation on any books or website links?

Comment: Hi user929153, I'm sorry this was migrated here unnecessarily, but this is way too broad a scope to be a good fit here; from [our FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask): "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Answer (score 2):

For C# development, in particular, I'd strongly recommend reading [Framework Design Guidelines](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321545613) and the [C# Programming Language](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321741765).  Both are very useful in providing a good, solid understanding about why the .NET framework and the C# language has its current design.  They also both (though the guidelines more so) have quite a few tips on standards and principles specific to C# and .NET.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to improve your general knowledge and principles, look at [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read). Note that Code Complete as mentioned by Leons is there as first book. Also Pragmatic Programmers and many, many more very important books. Focus on 3 areas:

1. software development in general (process, coding, ...)
2. object orientation (sounds easy but is not)
3. your language and frameworks of your language.

Answer (score 1):

[Clean Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882) can definitely help

But it seems we need longer answers:

If you are looking for a good book that can help you in your endeavour, I think [Clean Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882) can definitely help. It's written by Robert C. "Uncle Bob" Martin, whose biography is available here:  [biography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cecil_Martin)

To avoid further scripts from picking this post, I thought it would be interesting to point out that this author is also the author of the well known principle: [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Good read!